# Find saved games from internet and load to XBox 360

Tags: xbox-360

Is it possible to find "game save" files from the internet and then load them to XBox 360 via a USB flash disk? I have an Elite version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as save files are usually associated with your gamertag. Other files for holding high scores etc tend not to be so they can be shared by players on the same console, but actual progress saves are, to allow each player to have their own.

Answer (score 2):

The question wasn't if it was ethical, it was is it was possible. :)

The short answer is 'it is possible', but it requires some hacking and as the above commenters have noted, is frowned upon by Microsoft.

They have forums on it here: http://www.maxconsole.net/forumdisplay.php?208-Xbox-360-Game-Saves

I don't understand what the big deal is with gamerscore anyway.  I mean it's one thing to cheat in an online game, but to have a gamerscore of say 50000, who really cares?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to first say:

"It's easy, very easy... I was doing this from the age of 13"

## How to do it

download an xbox profile tool (tonnes out there... I use modio and eXtreme360 ... i think they're outdated now.

Secondly, download the wanted game save.

3. Play the game and make a new game save (aka Level 1, THIS WILL BE OVERWRITTEN)
4. Save your profile and game saves on a memory stick (unless you have a detachable HDD and transfer cable... memory stick is fine)
5. Load up your Xbox GameSave editor and open up your profile.
6. Create a Rehash/Resign Identity using your profile.
7. Locate the gamesave you downloaded.
8. Rehash & Resign the gamesave you downloaded with the Identity you created using your profiles new game save.
9. Import the freshly Rehashed and Resigned Game save onto your USB device.
10. BINGO! All sorted. ...you got what you came here for.

## How it works

When you play on an xbox with an account, you can save games.

When you save games, it saves the game with a long string

The long string is a bit of code which essentially means: ( This gamesave was saved on *Some time and date* and something about who the save belongs to, it's hashed... think of it as being encrypted, so you need the tool to make changes to the encrypted tag)

Any questions? ...please comment.

Thanks.

Comment: As SAGExSDX mentions this is not an acceptable use of the services, that's exactly why I do not condole these practices.

You asked the question, I simply answered with the answer, the use of this information is for educational purposes only.

Answer (score 1):

This practice is prohibited but is also highly frowned upon. There have been many cases of people who have hacked their Xbox 360s to facilitate this behavior and in doing so have boosted their Gamerscore and Achievement count.

Microsoft took a stance last year that when these sort of people are found, their Gamerscore would be reset to 0, that Gamerscore could never be attained again, and they visibly marked the account as having been moderated.

[Cheaters branded on Xbox Live, Gamerscores reset](http://www.joystiq.com/2008/03/25/cheaters-branded-on-xbox-live-gamerscore-reset/)

Answer (score 0):

That could be. First you must to download the she date.then you copy to your flash and then copy to your console after that you copy that to demo or games and apps or gamer profile.then open the game and select the store device.this work, 100% work in the gta v but be careful to don't delete the xbox360 things.good luck.

Comment: There are lots of grammatical errors in this answer can you fix those errors?

Answer (score -1):

I use horizon to mod game saves, but as for playing online and getting banned, it won't happen if you never play online to begin with.